# Group by Month in mysql even when the data is not present

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table "sales" like below

```
Customer    Date    Amount
Paul    15/01/2015  2000
Jonathan    15/01/2015  3000
Taylor  15/01/2015  2000
Mark    15/01/2015  3000
Paul    15/02/2015  2000
Jonathan    15/02/2015  3000
Paul    25/02/2015  4000
Jonathan    25/02/2015  5000
Jonathan    15/03/2015  2000
Jonathan    25/04/2015  5000
Taylor  25/04/2015  4000
Mark    25/04/2015  5000
Paul    25/05/2015  4000
Jonathan    25/05/2015  5000
Taylor  25/05/2015  4000
Mark    25/05/2015  5000
```

And in the report I wan to see it like below -

```
Customer    Month   Amount
Paul    201501  2000
Paul    201502  6000
Paul    201503  0
Paul    201504  0
Paul    201505  4000
```

Please tell me how to do it?

Update

```
Customer    Month   Amount
Paul    201501  2000
Paul    201502  6000
Paul    201503  0
Paul    201504  0
Paul    201505  4000
Jonathan    201501  3000
Jonathan    201502  8000
Jonathan    201503  2000
Jonathan    201504  5000
Jonathan    201505  5000
Taylor  201501  2000
Taylor  201502  0
Taylor  201503  0
Taylor  201504  4000
Taylor  201505  4000
Mark    201501  3000
Mark    201502  0
Mark    201503  0
Mark    201504  5000
Mark    201505  5000
```

Also I need to make this view for all the customers. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: post your GROUP BY query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, with a demo, using date you provided. Moreover, more data is added for simulation.

drop table sales;

SQL:

```
-- data
create table sales(Customer varchar(100), `Date` date, Amount int);
insert into sales values
('Paul',    '2015-01-15',  2000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-01-15',  3000),
('Taylor',  '2015-01-15',  2000),
('Mark',    '2015-01-15',  3000),
('Paul',    '2015-02-15',  2000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-02-15',  3000),
('Paul',    '2015-02-25',  4000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-02-25',  5000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-03-15',  2000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-04-15',  5000),
('Taylor',  '2015-04-25',  4000),
('Mark',    '2015-04-25',  5000),
('Paul',    '2015-05-25',  4000),
('Jonathan',    '2015-05-25',  5000),
('Taylor',  '2015-05-25',  4000),
('Mark',    '2015-05-25',  5000);
select * from sales;

-- query wanted
select 
    COALESCE(s.Customer, '') AS Customer, DATE_FORMAT(m2.cont_date, '%Y%m') AS Month, SUM(COALESCE(s.Amount, 0)) AS Amount
from (
    select (select MAX(`Date`) from sales) - interval (year.b * 10 + month.a) MONTH AS cont_date
    from (
        select 0 b union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union 
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) AS year
        CROSS JOIN
        (
        select 0 a union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union 
        select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) AS month        
    where (year.b * 10 + month.a) < (select timestampdiff(month, MIN(`Date`), MAX(`Date`)) + 1 from sales) ) m2
    LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.Customer = 'paul' AND DATE_FORMAT(m2.cont_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(s.`Date`, '%Y%m')
GROUP BY Month;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from sales;
+----------+------------+--------+
| Customer | Date       | Amount |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Paul     | 2015-01-15 |   2000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-01-15 |   3000 |
| Taylor   | 2015-01-15 |   2000 |
| Mark     | 2015-01-15 |   3000 |
| Paul     | 2015-02-15 |   2000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-02-15 |   3000 |
| Paul     | 2015-02-25 |   4000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-02-25 |   5000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-03-15 |   2000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-04-15 |   5000 |
| Taylor   | 2015-04-25 |   4000 |
| Mark     | 2015-04-25 |   5000 |
| Paul     | 2015-05-25 |   4000 |
| Jonathan | 2015-05-25 |   5000 |
| Taylor   | 2015-05-25 |   4000 |
| Mark     | 2015-05-25 |   5000 |
+----------+------------+--------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- query wanted
mysql> select
    ->     COALESCE(s.Customer, '') AS Customer, DATE_FORMAT(m2.cont_date, '%Y%m') AS Month, SUM(COALESCE(s.Amount, 0)) AS Amount
    -> from (
    ->     select (select MAX(`Date`) from sales) - interval (year.b * 10 + month.a) MONTH AS cont_date
    ->     from (
    ->         select 0 b union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    ->         select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) AS year
    ->         CROSS JOIN
    ->         (
    ->         select 0 a union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    ->         select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) AS month
    ->     where (year.b * 10 + month.a) < (select timestampdiff(month, MIN(`Date`), MAX(`Date`)) + 1 from sales) ) m2
    ->     LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.Customer = 'paul' AND DATE_FORMAT(m2.cont_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(s.`Date`, '%Y%m')
    -> GROUP BY Month;
+----------+--------+--------+
| Customer | Month  | Amount |
+----------+--------+--------+
| Paul     | 201501 |   2000 |
| Paul     | 201502 |   6000 |
|          | 201503 |      0 |
|          | 201504 |      0 |
| Paul     | 201505 |   4000 |
+----------+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thanks for your answer. When I'm grouping by the customer (as I have more than 50 customers in my table) and Month, the "0" that should come, is not coming.In your given example it's showing 201501 after 201410. Please Let me know what to do

Comment: Use date_format. select DATE_FORMAT('2015-01-15', '%Y%m'); it returns '201501'

Comment: What am I trying to say is  - when there is no entry for a month in the amount Column it should show "0", as per our requirement. But in stead it is not showing any value and skipping the month. In the example given by you it should show 0 in the Amount column for 201411 and 201412, but is not showing anything.

Comment: I am currently showing 24 months by select union as you have described. I want to show the months that do not have any data in amount column - like in the question month 201503 doesn't have any data, but still it should be shown in the report. And against 201503 in Month column, the amount should be 0

Comment: I just updated the post and expand the range it can handle. Now it can handle up to 8 years, about 100 months. Pls try again.

Comment: I'm Sorry. I' think I couldn't make the question clear. I'm re-posting it with more clarification. I have updated the question.

Comment: Update with your new data.

Comment: This is working perfectly. I still have a query. Can group by "Customer" along with month? I want the same data for all the Customer.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for doing all customers together. The post method can only handle single customer so far.

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Comment: This helped me right away apart from the very last point of the question. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a in-line table, with all the months, and then join your sales table on it.

Something like this:

```
SELECT s.customer_name as Customer,
CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y) as Month,
s.amount as Amount
    FROM (
       SELECT '01' AS m UNION ALL SELECT '02' UNION ALL SELECT '03' UNION ALL 
       SELECT '04' UNION ALL SELECT '05' UNION ALL SELECT '06' UNION ALL 
       SELECT '07' UNION ALL SELECT '08' UNION ALL SELECT '09' UNION ALL 
       SELECT '10' UNION ALL SELECT '11' UNION ALL SELECT '12') AS months
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT '2015' AS y UNION ALL SELECT '2016') AS years
    LEFT JOIN sales_table AS s
       ON DATE_FORMAT(s.date, '%Y-%c') = CONCAT(years.y, '-', months.m)
    GROUP BY CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y)
```